# Importing all folders with SASS files inside

Tags: css, sass, bem

I'm using BEM methodology, so every SCSS file is placed in individual folder, so, if I want to create another block I have to create folder, then place my SCSS file inside, then write another import like this `@import "../blocks/new-block/new-block";`. Is it possible to import every SCSS file from every folder from `blocks` directory? Maybe something like this `@import "../blocks/**/*.scss`

Comment: Let us know more about your stack: gulp, rails etc

Comment: I'm using gulp and ruby-sass as implementation of sass.

Comment: Check this out https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-glob

Comment: That's what I need, thank you!